# Trying to validate email field against database to prevent duplciates in contact form

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, contact-form

I have a contact form on my site, I want to prevent users with the same email from contacting more than once.

On the mySQL database that stores the data I made the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE find_email(emailaddr VARCHAR(60))
BEGIN

DECLARE form_email VARCHAR(60);
SET form_email=emailaddr;

SELECT count(*)
FROM wordpress.cf7dbplugin_submits
WHERE form_name='Register'
AND field_name LIKE '%email%'
AND field_value=form_email;
END //
```

This way I could get a number from how many times an email address was in the database.

In my PHP file I did this

```
Global $res;
$res = $mydb->query("CALL find_email");
if($res>0)
{
echo "<script>alert('This email address is already in use!')</script>";
}
else
{
$tableName = $this->getSubmitsTableName();
            $parametrizedQuery = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (`submit_time`, `form_name`, `field_name`, `field_value`, `field_order`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";
            $parametrizedFileQuery = "INSERT INTO `$tableName` (`submit_time`, `form_name`, `field_name`, `field_value`, `field_order`, `file`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)";
            $order = 0;
            $noSaveFields = $this->getNoSaveFields();
            $foundUploadFiles = array();
            global $mydb;
 }
```

If I change my code and manually set $res to be 0, the form works like it's supposed to. Otherwise nothing happens when I click the submit button.

Hope I put enough details, thanks in advance to anyone who has a solution.

Comment: why don't you pass any parameter to your stored procedure? Shouldn't it be ("CALL find_email(some_email)")?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Sorry but can you elaborate? Is "some-email" supposed to be a specific email?

Comment: you've created a stored procedure that takes one string argument. When you call this stored procedure, you pass no arguments, which looks accidental. I was thinking about something like: $res = $mydb->query("CALL find_email($some_email)");

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz would "$some_email" be literally what I type, or would that be defined in the stored procedure?

Comment: on the PHP level you construct dynamic string which you will pass to the MySQL server. Variables put inside "" strings will display their values and inside '' - won't. So $some_email = "xyz@example.com" $x = "CALL find_email($some_email)" will result in "CALL find_email(xyz@example.com)" and this is what you pass to the database.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz So do I literally just need to change that one line in the PHP level?

Comment: well... just try it and see if it works... what do you expect? it's a guess.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz It doesn't work. Still the same non-responsiveness. I might not know what I'm talking about here, but how is the PHP finding out what is being submitted in the email field? Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You've complicated all this stuff way too much. First, don't use stored procedures in MySQL if you really don't have to. Instead, use pure:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%value%'
```

Second. You should provide HTML of the form so that I know what are your $_POST variables. FOr example if your form looks like:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" />
</form>
```

Then you'll access the email inside PHP script with `$_POST['mail']`.

Third. It depends if one PHP script/framework controller handles both displaying a raw form (get) and submitting it (post) or are they distinct PHP scripts/controllers. If you use one file, it should look like:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // process - check SQL and eventually display javascript alert
} else  { // get
  // display the form
}
```

Hope that helps. I suggest you to read some tutorials, since asking questions may not always help, if you do not understand what are you asking about.

Comment: The name is of the input is "register-email"

Comment: it should be _ instead of -.
Anyway, make the PHP code look like:
$db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%$_POST['register_email']%'");

Comment: I'm sorry, but stackoverflow is a question-answer site, it's not a forum. If you get a 500 error and you do not check server logs, I'm unable to help you. Read basic PHP tutorials on the web and use more google, sorry.

Comment: If you still care here's what the server log said:

[22-Feb-2013 21:49:28 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7-to-database-extension\CF7DBPlugin.php on line 522